# How to get pid from pthread

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

in RH Linux, every pthread is mapping to a pid, which can be monitored in tools such as htop. but how can i get the pid of a thread? getpid() just return the pid of the main thread.

Comment: [Linux 2.6 replaced LinuxThreads with NPTL](http://drdobbs.com/open-source/184406204), Linux now follows POSIX and correctly returns the same PID for each thread.

Comment: You should consider "accept"ing answers that you find useful.

Comment: Steve-o: Maybe so, but linux still creates a separate process for each thread (each thread gets its own /proc/<pid>, where <pid> is different than the main thread/process)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[pthread_self();](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_self.html)**

Can be called to return the ID of the calling thread.

Also PID is process Id, A thread has thread Id not PID. All threads running in the same process will have the same PID.

Comment: Als the downvote is because what you're saying is wrong. Linux threads can in fact be represented by a pid, as they are lightweight processes. In fact the following function exists in Linux unistd.h: pid_t gettid(void). Windows, on the other hand, has true independent thread Ids.

Answer (score 32):

There are two thread values that get confused.  [pthread_self()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) will return the POSIX thread id; [gettid()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/gettid.2.html) will return the OS thread id.  The latter is linux specific and not guaranteed to be portable but probably what you are really looking for.

**EDIT** As PlasmaHH notes, `gettid()` is called via `syscall()`.  From the `syscall()` man page:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/syscall.h>
   #include <sys/types.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       pid_t tid;

       tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
   }
```

Comment: Note that gettid() has no glibc wrapper and needs to be called via syscall()

Comment: @ PlasmaHH - Right, I should add that.  Fortuitously the syscall man page uses it as an example.

Comment: @Maxim: Interestingly, with a new maintainer the referenced glibc issue has been reopened.

Comment: @NathanKidd yep, the old maintainer was not overly cooperative )

Answer (score 2):

A PID is a Process ID, not a thread ID. Threads running on the same process will obviously all be associated with the same PID.

Because pthreads tries to be portable you cannot obtain the ID of the underlying OS thread directly. It's even possible that there isn't an underlying OS thread.

Comment: Or rather, since NPTL threads are no longer registered as processes.

Answer (score 1):

pthread_self does *not* get the tid. it proviedes a handle or pointer of type pthread_t for usage in pthread functions.

see here for an example what a real world program might return:

http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/212807-full

Answer (score 1):

Actually `pthread_self` return `pthread_t` and not a integer thread id you can work with, the following helper function will get you that in a portable way across different POSIX systems.

```
uint64_t gettid() {
    pthread_t ptid = pthread_self();
    uint64_t threadId = 0;
    memcpy(&threadId, &ptid, std::min(sizeof(threadId), sizeof(ptid)));
    return threadId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Threads have tids (threadIds), and all threads run in the same process (pid).  So, your threads should all have the same pid assuming they're created in the same process, bu they'll have different tids.

pthread_self() gives tid, and getpid() gets the pid.

Answer (score -1):

I think the function you are looking for is [pthread_self](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_self.html)