# get thread last scheduled CPU/core

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a number of living threads in my application for which I have `pthread_t` IDs and can get other IDs if necessary. Those are stored in a separate array.

How can I determine the ID/number of the CPU that a specific thread is currently running (or one it was recently run on) calling from another thread.

`sched_getcpu(2)` only works for the calling thread and `pthread_getaffinity_np` only gives me the allowed cpu mask. `/proc` is being equally as useless only giving me a CPU ID for the whole process.

I need this for debugging/tuning NUMA aware code.

Comment: What does it even mean to be running on a specific core? The kernel is free to switch core 1000s of times a second (although it hopefully doesn't). You can stop that by forcing the affinity, of course, but that's another matter.

Comment: The information might be in one of the files in `/proc/$pid/task/$tid`, but this sounds like an imprecise and probably misguided endeavor. By the time you read the information it may very well be wrong.

Comment: I am not worried much about the accuracy of the result that I get, but I need to check wether my threads get scheduled on the CPUs I want them to be scheduled on.

Comment: @ams this is exactly the kind of information I want. I know that scheduling can change a lot, but I am working of a 700 core supercomputer and I get a whole cpu set reserved for my application. Since in such a NUMA system memory is not necessarily local to the CPU I need to be careful where I have which threads scheduled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on Lnux you could get the `tid` for every thread by calling `gettid()`.

Then look up the CPU id by reading the 39th element from  `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stat`.

(where `pid` is read via `getpid()`)

---

See also:

- [How to get the CPU id via /proc file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131483/694576)
- [How to get the LW-process id for a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7271559/694576)

Comment: Thanks, isn't exactly the dream solution, but does the trick.